# c# application connected to the database - cannot detach

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, detach

When I create new database with C# and create a table, I am able to close and open connection to it. If I try to detach the database in the same session of my application, it tells me I can't.
If I restart the application, then open the database, then close and detach - It works.
Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

P.S. I have tried with SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE, which works, but changes my database permissions, and I really don't want this.

My connection string:

```
myConn.ConnectionString = String.Format("Server={0};Integrated security=SSPI;", serverName);
```

My detach string:

```
str = string.Format("EXEC sp_detach_db '{0}'", databaseName);
```

Comment: do you try do detach the database from within a connection to that same database ?

Comment: Probably. I connect on application load, and disconnect at application close. The problem is just after db creation. Later, if I open the application and connect, I can detach.

Comment: you cannot detach a database that is in use. So before sending the call to detach first you must switch to another database, for example like this 'use master'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot detach a database that is in use.
So if you are connected to the same database that you want to detach, then switch to database master first.

```
str = string.Format("use master GO EXEC sp_detach_db '{0}'", databaseName);
```

Comment: Yes. Totally right. Thank you very much :) And sorry, I am quite green into c# and sql.

Answer (score 1):

Hello friend are you using : "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;" ?

if **NO** then use it to detach your database

`Server MyServer = new Server("your server name");
MyServer .DetachDatabase("name of database",true);`

if **yes** please specify your question

Comment: I use this:
                str = string.Format("EXEC sp_detach_db '{0}'", databaseName);
                com = new SqlCommand(str, myConn);
                // Execute the command to SQL
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                myConn.Close();

Comment: edit your question and put this info there, not here

Comment: using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

namespace db_server
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Server MyS = new Server(".");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void DeAttach_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyS.DetachDatabase(comboBox1.Text, true);
            MessageBox.Show("" + MyS.Name);
        }
    } }

Comment: @StoyanIvanov please try the previous code it worked for me

Comment: Is this better than direct string sql queries?